# Database normalization and repeated values in different rows

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

I think I was under the false impression that part of normalizing a data base is replacing duplicate values in rows with id numbers. Consider the following:

```
(employ table) 

id(pk   name    branch
-------------------------------
1       dan      nyc_union
2       ron      la_skidrow
3       seth     nyc_union
```

The same branch can appear more than once and there is only one nyc_union branch, so to avoid spelling mistakes (NYC, ny) and redundancy we create a second table for branches and link it with a relationship to the employe table.

But after reading the following https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/third-normal-form.php

If you look at the table example they have in the link above, to satisfy the second rule of normalization they use a table which repeats the value for branch without creating another table, and yet they claim it's normalized. I've seen other similar examples.

What if we had more than one branch per location would that change the answer? Meaning now we can just put this attribute in the employe tablre without creating another table?

In which cases do we have more then one column of real values, not links to ids?

**IN CONCLUSION**

As a rule of thumb to follow normalization we should use only one 'real non linked id value' per table and the rest of the values should be links to ids in other tables. Is this correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  Presumably, you are misunderstanding the referenced material.

Comment: If you added more columns for data on the branch (e.g. address, products, etc.) then you would have **multiple** repeated columns. In that case you should replace all branch columns with an "id" and create a BRANCH table instead.

Comment: It's really about what branch is. If PK for branch is whatever this stringy values are, than the sample table is normalized. Contrary to what people frequently believe, it's not about referencing everything with automatically generated numbers. It's really about Primary Keys - it just so happens, that a lot of people take it easy and use integers as Primary Keys exclusively for everything.

Comment: What part in your  reading cause the confusion? Adding a Branch table make sense.

Comment: Creating a related table for branches can help to standardize those values.  You could also standardize them with a check constraint or entry constraints in a user interface.  Normalization does not require creation of a related table for every case in which there are repeated values in a column.

Comment: @nimdil Its easy, faster and few bytes store PK as number than strings.

Comment: Per your revised question, if you had more than one branch per city, that is, if city was an attribute of branch and you wanted to select or sort by city (as @TheImpaler indicated) then you should create a separate table for the branch, with a branch ID that does not include the city name.  (The branch ID does not have to be numeric, but that's a very different topic.)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza its also meaningless. The numbers have no relation to the data. Also there is a push to start using GUID/UUID instead which are actually pretty big

Comment: What is your one specific not-too-broad question? PS "the false impression that part of normalizing a data base is replacing duplicate values in rows with id numbers" Yes, doing that is not normalization. No, it doesn't avoid spelling mistakes, it just has them happen in a different place--look at the same spelling mistake in both designs. PS The way to "follow normalization" is to no use a rule of thumb but to follow normalization. Find out what it is.

Comment: This is too broad. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Quote just what you need & relate it to your problem. Make your post self-contained. PS The presentation at the link you give is not useful. It does not even define 3NF (or transitive FD) properly. PS Dozens of DB design textbooks (good to bad) are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.)

Comment: The link's video even gets "(functionally) depends on" wrong. It is worthless.

Comment: @philipxy I didn't see the video, I was linking to their table and example. But you are right, since it was the article that I've linked to that got me so confused, maybe I should have asked if what's described there is considered proper normalization.

Comment: Yes. So many questions are asked by people not knowing the definitions of the very terms they are using and/or literally not knowing what (algorithm) they are doing--and their problem is not their perceived stuckness but their not knowing. (Observe how the (accepted) answer by LaurenzAlbe does not actually justify their decomposition or say anything you can apply to this example or any other example to come up with an answer. It just mentions a couple relevant facts that they used (soundly or not) to come up with their decompostion. And hence your commented questions on the (non-)answer.)

Comment: Yes I knew I had a problem with my fundamental understanding, but I couldn't find the right resources. The article I've linked to is number second or third in googles search result for such terms as: "database normalization".  Thanks for your great and much needed tip about Stanford. Do you have other online resources about the subject you can recommend?

Comment: "Dozens of DB design textbooks (good to bad) are online free in pdf." When you find them see what they're like & read reviews. Decide on 2 or 3 to follow concurrently, they all have problems that others usually won't. Date's Intro, Ullman et al's Complete, Ramez et al's Fundamentals are ok, Connolly & Begg is bad. Search my answers--read ones with the term 'predicate' first. [Here's Darwen on DBs though not normalization.](https://bookboon.com/en/author/0908031c-ce02-9b86-11e6-6dd7d2c299d1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point about normalization is not to avoid duplicate values: several people can have the same name, but that is not a reason to break out a `names` table and reference it with a foreign key.

Normalization comes into play where there is another column, for example

```
id   name    branch       address
---------------------------------
1    dan     nyc_union    1 Union Street
2    ron     la_skidrow   22 Skid Row
3    seth    nyc_union    1 Union Street
```

In this case you have a “functional dependency”, namely the address of the branch depends on the branch. That is, for any two employees in the same branch, the address would be the same.

To normalize this denormalized table, we'd move `branch` and `address` to its own table with `branch` as the primary key and change the employee table to the one in your question, where `branch` is a foreign key to our new branch table.

This has two advantages:

- It cannot happen that someone updates the address in one employee record, but forgets to perform the same update in all other employees of that branch (which would cause an inconsistency).
- You don't have to store the same address over and over and save some space.

Comment: Let's say there could be only one person with the same name, so the name is unique, but we still use the id as unique pk. Should we then use a different table for the name?

Comment: Only if there is some other column that functionally depends on the name (which is unlikely).

Comment: So only if we need to add dependent data, thanks I think it clicked finally

Comment: Well if you have a Phone number, Birthday associated with that Name, then you create a table `USER` for ir.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza an phone number is never associated with a name, but with a person. And the employees table has only one record per person I'll assume.